# Adding border pushes wrapper up and makes div contents into an overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to find a way around this and have Googled for over an hour, but I am not sure how to get around it. If I add a border to the div wrapper it pushes the wrapper up to the top of the page while the floated divs stay in the same position. I have tried fiddling with overflow properties, and relative and absolute positioning.

The css is here

```
html, body 
{ 
        height : 100% ;
        margin : 0 ;
        padding : 0 
}

html { background : #FFFFFF } 

#wrapper 
{ 
       background : #0066FF ;
       color : white ;
       height : 780px ;
       width : 1620px ;
       font : 16px "Arial", sans-serif ;
       margin : auto ;
       border : 4px solid black 
}



#header 
{ 
         height : 90px ;
         text-align : center ;
         color : black ; 
         background : #66CCFF ;
         padding : 3px 0px ;
         margin : 100px 0 10px ;
         clear : both
}

#header h1 
{
        font-weight : bold ;
        font-size : 35px ;
        padding : 20px 0
}

#left 
{ 
        float : left ;
        width : 180px ;
        height : 660px ;
        background-color : #66CCFF ;
        padding : 5px ;
        margin-right : 25px
}

#content 
{ 
     float : left ;
     background-color : #66CCFF ; 
     color : black ;
     height : 660px ; 
     width : 1140px ;
     margin-right : 25px ;
     padding : 5px 
}

#right 
{ 
       float : left ;
       background-color : #66CCFF ;
       color : black ;
       width : 220px ;
       height : 660px ;
       padding : 5px 
}

#footer 
{ 
       background-color : black ; 
       clear : both 
}
```

I have also done a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mocqzsas/) which contains the HTML and an example of the wrapper with the darker blue background jumping up the page.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is usually caused by default white space and padding. Browsers have a default padding setting of usaully like 5 or 10 px, which is really frusterating at times. Of course this is not always what's causing the problem. Whenever I encounter a problem like this I try adding padding 0 and margin 0 to every single object in my code, even the html and body, example:

```
#example {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
};
```

try that [I see you have it in a few, but not every single object]. 
I don't know for sure if this will fix the issue, but it's worth a try and it often works for me. This is a frustrating problem for anyone.

EDIT: [removed comment about closing tags]

Comment: H Chris, I thought my closing brackets were enough. Is there a limit on how many selectors you can have inside of your opening and closing brackets?  Also, I had used a reset.css file which reset the margin and padding to 0, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Yeah scratch what I said about the closing tags. I think I got a little confused, doing that will actually cause an error. I apologize. Yeah doing a CSS reset should've fixed that problem. I know for me I had to manually insert the code into the actual CSS values to make it work. Of course I could be wrong, it's just sort of what I played around with that worked, there might be better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, an answer to my own question. I managed to get round this by leaving the header div outside of the wrapper. That way I could put a border around the header and wrapper without the page moving upwards. Of course I used border-bottom : none on the header, and border-top : none on the wrapper then the border looked fine with the content where it should be.

I don't think it is the best answer because I have not fully identified what caused the problem, but I will keep looking.

Comment: Also to further expand on this it is a common problem of "block formatting contexts". The upper and lower margin of two divs can collapse causing problems unless a new block formatting context is created. You can read about it here http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/ I used the micros clearfix hack which is here http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/